# I have A text file with id no name and grades i want to extract the ID no, and grades then calculate the average and append it to another file

Tags: file, append, extract

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("students.txt", true));
    do
      { 
         //get the info from user to write to file
         System.out.print("Enter The Student ID: ");
         idNo = keyIn.nextLine(); 
         System.out.print("Enter The Student Name: ");
         name = keyIn.nextLine();
         System.out.print("Enter The Student Grades: ");
         grades = keyIn.nextInt();
         keyIn.nextLine(); //clear buffer

```
     out.println(idNo +" " +name +" " +grades);        //write line to output file

     System.out.print("Do You Have Another Student To Process: ");
     response = keyIn.next().charAt(0);
     keyIn.nextLine(); //clear buffer


  }while(response != 'n');     
    //close files
  out.close();
    //in.close();
```

break;

case 2:                // Write Student Test Marks To results.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer >();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       String temp[]=line.split(" ");
       if (map.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(temp[0]))) {
           int val=hmap.get[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])];
           val+=Integer.parseInt(temp[2]);
           map.put(Integer.parseInt(temp[0]),val);
       } else {
          map.put(Integer.parseInt(temp[0]),Integer.parseInt(temp[2]));
       }
    }
}
try{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("results.txt", "UTF-8");
    Iterator it = hmap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        writer.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: OMG thats crazy code, thanks for your reply but i havent a clue what all that means my java is basic and i dont even know where to start with that

Comment: In the first half of the code i'm using Hashmap(i.e. pair<ID,grades>) for storing sum of grades for same IDs. Then writing the same hashmap values(ID, grades) to another file in second half. Hashmap is like dictionary with unique keys.

Comment: hey thats way above my skills ive never even heard of hashmap

Comment: Actually that is the only way I found to save ID and grades together and use the same to write into file finally. I used the hashmap with presumption that your file has multiple lines with same IDs repeated, in that case we need to keep old values which we have already read and sum the new value to old value that is there in hashmap and update hashmap with new sum. Hashmap maintains unique keys.